# JDBCJobStore Confusion in Quartz Schdular

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz `JDBCJobStore` and have following job definition

```
JobDetail job=newJob(HelloJob.class).withIdentity("demo11", "group11").
         usingJobData("jobSays", "Hello Vikas")
        .usingJobData("myFloatValue", 3.141f).storeDurably(true).
         build();
```

and trigger as

```
Trigger trigger=newTrigger().withIdentity("Trigger11","group11")
                .startNow().withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.
                 cronSchedule("0 0/1 * * * ?")).build();
```

I was of impression that Quartz will store `jobSays` and `myFloatValue` in the database but I am unable see any such property in the database.

Is there a way to store these `JobData` in the database?

Here is the `quartz.property` file

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = MyScheduler
org.quartz.threadPool.class=org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 3
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDS 
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quartz
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.user=root
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.password=root
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.MSSQLDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quartz stores job data as BLOB datatype in QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS table.

Please check there.